# Python itertools: Combining predicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

This is Project Euler problem 2:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
>   be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
>   exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

One possible straightforward method is:

```
def fib_even(n):
    previous, current = 0, 1
    sum_fib = 0
    while current <= n:
        previous, current = current, previous + current
        if current % 2 == 0:
            sum_fib += current
    return sum_fib
```

Then I tried to do it in a sort of functional way with a “pure” generator:

```
def fibonacci_generator():
    curr_fib, next_fib = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield curr_fib
        curr_fib, next_fib = next_fib, curr_fib + next_fib

print(sum(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < n, fibonacci_generator()))))
```

This version is inefficient because the same job (yielding) is done multiple times.

My question: What is the functional way to generate the Fibonacci numbers once,  until the some limit is reached and filtering the odd numbers at the same time. (Without altering the generator in the second version.)

For reference, the first version timeit for one billion gives:

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 10 µs per loop
```

The second version timeit for one billion gives:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: That is the functional way. Python just doesn't support functional programming styles with the same efficiency as other languages.

Comment: You already have the functional way, and your not-functional way is basically the functional way, but inlined. Maybe if this were PyPy or Jython or something, the system could JIT inline the second version to speed it up, but on CPython, calling those lambdas isn't going to be good for speed.

Comment: An outside-the-box solution is to notice that every third Fibonacci number is even (**0**, 1, 1, **2**, 3, 5, **8**, 13, 21, **34**, ...). This means you can just slice the sequence rather than test every value for evenness.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the filtering in the generator will be faster:

```
def my_fibonacci_generator():
    curr_fib, next_fib = 0, 1
    while True:
        if not curr_fib % 2:
            yield curr_fib
        curr_fib, next_fib = next_fib, curr_fib + next_fib


n = 4000000
sum(takewhile(lambda i: i < n, my_fibonacci_generator())
```

Runs in less than half the time:

```
In [10]: timeit (sum(filterfalse(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, takewhile(lambda x: x < n, fibonacci_generator()))))
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.1 µs per loop

In [11]: timeit sum(takewhile(lambda i: i < n, my_fibonacci_generator()))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.65 µs per loop

In [12]: sum(filterfalse(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, takewhile(lambda x: x < n, fibonacci_generator())))
Out[12]: 4613732

In [13]:  sum(takewhile(lambda i: i < n, my_fibonacci_generator()))
Out[13]: 4613732
```

It is the cost of the lambda that is slowing down your own function. Unless you can use a builtin line `map(operator.add` instead of the lambda equivalent then a functional approach is always going to suffer.

The only way to get near the same runtime without modifying is to do the filter first:

```
In [57]: timeit sum(takewhile(lambda x: x < n, filter(lambda x: x & 1, fibonacci_generator())))
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.93 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to find a solution (if possible) without altering the generator in the second version.

Comment: @blackened, it is the second lambda that is killing you

Comment: Yes. That is why I brought it here.

Comment: @blackened,  you have to filter using a lambda if you don't do the filtering in the function, it is not the ifilterfalse call that is killing you. `sum(filter(None, takewhile(lambda x: x < n, fibonacci_generator())))` would run efficiently also 
`